# kubuntu 12.04 comes with nothing?

Tags: linux, kubuntu

i downloaded and installed kubuntu 12.04 on my laptop today. the dvd was 3.2GB. but there is no firefox, vlc, flash, c compiler or anything useful for that matter. exactly what is taking up 3.2GB? it has the same resources as ubuntu 13.10 cd which is around 960MB. this is just too frustrating. when the internet connection is limited, one might need to compile packages from source using one's backup files. i don't understand why kubuntu hasn't even provided a gcc compiler so that one may at the very least compile from souce code using ./configure... so the bottom line question is, WHAT exactly is taking up 3.2GB in kubuntu 12.04. please enlighten me guys

Comment: Have you looked in the package manager? There are a lot of packages that come on those DVDs that aren't installed by default.

Comment: I'm guessing you've just selected the most basic of the basic installation template. There are *lots* of packages on that dvd.

Comment: i installed manually. and i took a look at the package manager. cannot install a single package without internet connection... whereas i would just use apt-get anyway. it's a shame i only have these issues with kde distros.. yet that's my favorite desktop interface..

Comment: i am clearly missing something here, but what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to check a system what, if any, software is installed. I'll name a few from very specific down to very general:

1. In KDE: press ALT+F2. A small text interface appears. Type "firefox" and press enter. Firefox will start, if it is installed.
2. On any terminal emulator or virtual terminal: `dpkg --get-selections` this will print out a list of *all* installed packages. Pipe through `grep` to narrow it down, e. g. `dpkg --get-selections | grep firefox` This will return a few hits if Firefox is installed.
3. On any terminal emulator or virtual terminal: use `whereis`, e. g. `whereis firefox` and the command will return a path or a message that no program by the name is installed.
4. On any terminal emulator or virtual terminal: use `find`, e. g. `find /usr -iname "*firefox*"` will return all instances of files containing "firefox" in their names and which are below /usr.

Comment: i know how to find files, but the problem is that the files i want like firefox or vlc is not there and if i try to install them, they wont install without internet. if i want to compile from source, i would need c compiler, which in turn needs to ne installed from the internet. just looking for a way to set up the machine for general use without internet. i searched through the package manager and everything

Comment: Check you /etc/apt/sources.list file. There should be an entry right at the top starting with `# deb cdrom:[foo bar] precise main`. Remove the comment sign and run `apt-get update` with the installation disk in the drive. You should now be able to install software packages from the DVD.